# How to remove a single <li> from a <ul> using jQuery click()

Tags: jquery, html

I need to remove a single list element after left clicking on it. I can remove the entire list but not a single element

I've looked around on Stack but nothing seems to answer my specific problem

```
(function(){

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#likeform").submit(function(event) {
      var input = $(this).children("input[name='thing']")
      var thing = $(input).val()
      $("#likes").append("<li>" + thing + "</li>")
      $(input).val("")
      event.preventDefault()
    });

    $("#likes").click(function() {
        alert("test=true")
        $("#likes").remove()

    });

  })
})()





<body>
  <h1>What do you like?</h1>
  <form id=likeform>
    <input name=thing placeholder="a thing you like" size=30>
    <input type=submit>
  </form>

  <ul id=likes></ul>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure if I need to add specific ID's to each list element.

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: How do you want to determine which element to remove? Based on index? Content? Id? Class?

Comment: I've updated my question, after clicking on the list element it should be removed

Comment: `$(this).remove()`?

Comment: no i've tried that it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the click handler on the `li`, not the `ul`. Then you can refer to the element they clicked on with `this`.

Use event delegation so this will work with dynamically-added elements.

```
$("#likes").on("click", "li", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```